# PdfSharp - Wrong PDF page settings when document is opened in Acrobat

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I have written a piece of code which uses the PdfSharp library. The instance of `PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument` created saves to disk as expected. The right content is displayed, but onto the wrong page settings.

The default page settings for PdfSharp are:

1. `PdfSharp.PageSizes.A4`
2. `PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Portrait`

My problem is that these settings seem to override the required settings.

I create the instance of `PdfDocument` class and adds a new instance of `PdfPage` class to its Pages collection property. Then, I setup the page like this:

1. `PdfDocument.Pages[0].Size = PdfSharp.PageSizes.Letter`
2. `PdfDocument.Pages[0].Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Landscape`
3. I draw the strings (this works fine)
4. I save the document to disk (this works fine)
5. `Process.Start(myPdfFilename)` - then Acrobat Reader opens with my
   document.
6. The page settings are A4 - Portrait...

I'm quite confused. I know of an option within Acrobat Reader that allows the user to change the page orientation without changing the text direction. No matter whether I check this option or not, still the wrong settings keep going.

Anyone has an idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For some strange reason, PdfSharp seems not to behave the same with both the following:

Example 1 - It doesn't seem to associate the instance of PdfPage class to the PdfDocument even though the page settings are correct while calling and after having called the PdfDocument.Save() method.

```
var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument();
var pdfPage = pdfDoc.AddPage();
pdfPage.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Landscape;
pdfPage.Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.Letter;
pdfPage.Rotate = 0;
pdfDoc.Save(filename);
```

Example 2 - The same here...

```
var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument();
pdfDoc.Pages.Add();
pdfDoc.Pages[0].Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Landscape;
pdfDoc.Pages[0].Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.Letter;
pdfDoc.Pages[0].Rotate = 0;
pdfDoc.Save(filename);
```

Example 3 - This seems to have solved my problem

```
var pdfPage = new PdfPage();
pdfPage.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Landscape;
pdfPage.Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.Letter;
pdfPage.Rotate = 0;
var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument();
pdfDoc.Pages.Add(pdfPage);
pdfDoc.Save(filename);
```

Anyone has any idea of what am I missing here? I seem to do the same in either of these examples, as far as I'm concerned.

Solution is:

```
var pdfPage = new PdfPage();
pdfPage.Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.Letter;
pdfPage.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Landscape;
pdfPage.Rotate = 0;
var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument();
pdfDoc.Pages.Add(pdfPage);
pdfDoc.Save(filename);
```

Set size first.

Thanks for any comments and/or answers!

Answer (score 7):

I examined this issue.
It seems you have to set "page.Size" before setting "page.Orientation" to landscape.
This is a bug because the order shouldn't matter here.

Order matters - but the workaround is simple: swap 2 lines in Example 1 and you're done (BTW: no need to set Rotate to 0).

PDFsharp Forum:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/